# How can i play google drive video in to android VideoView or in Iframe

Tags: java, android, video-streaming, android-videoview, drive

I want to play video uploaded on google drive in android application VideoView or in iframe but getting problem to play video in android application.

```
Uri uri=Uri.parse("https://drive.google.com/open?id=XXXXXXXX/preview");
videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
videoView.setVideoURI(uri);
videoView.requestFocus();
videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
        videoView.start();
    }
});
```

play video in VideoView from google drive /preview url. same for iframe also

Comment: Hello, what is the issue you are having? Is there a stack trace?

Comment: 2019-03-30 14:08:56.306 32703-32703/com.XX.XX W/MediaPlayer: Couldn't open https://drive.google.com/file/d/XXXX/preview: java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider: https://drive.google.com/file/d/XXXX/preview